# How to hide out of stock product and set product limit per page for custom product collection in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, out-of-stock

I am using Magento 1.9

I have created one custom listing page and in this page I have displayed all products. I have added below code for collection.

> app/design/frontend/my_vendor/default/template/catalog/product/view/products.phtml

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                            ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                            ->setPageSize(30);
```

Now I want to hide out of stock products as well
So how can I achieve this using above code?

I also want to show only limited no. of products selected in limiter.

Right now I have set 30 products per page(look above code) so whenever I click on "60" from limiter it only shows 30 products per page instead of 60 product per page.

So how can I fix this?

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if not solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this below code :

**Method 1 :**

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                            ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                            ->setPageSize(30);
$_productCollection->getSelect()->join('cataloginventory_stock_status', 'cataloginventory_stock_status.product_id = e.entity_id', array('stock_status'));
$_productCollection->getSelect()->where("`cataloginventory_stock_status`.`stock_status` = 1");
```

**Method 2 :**

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                            ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                            ->joinField('is_in_stock',
                            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                            'is_in_stock',
                            'product_id=entity_id',
                            'is_in_stock=1',
                            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                            'left')
                            ->setPageSize(30);
```

Comment: which method is most effective. I have already used first method and tested one or two products and it seems to working fine. so it's 100% effective?

Comment: Both method is best for use but, Method 2 is more better.

Comment: You can accept and upvote answer if this answer useful :)

Comment: Thank you I have used method 2 and it worked better than first method

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy Coding :)

Comment: I am facing other issue regarding product limit per page. So I have edited my question. Please check

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code

```
$productCollection= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                            ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                            ->setPageSize(30);


$_productCollection = Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
    ->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);
```